# Visio 2013 - How to change default connector behaviour (shape and fill considered a bonus)

Tags: microsoft-visio, default-settings, microsoft-visio-2013

I'd like to be able to have curved connectors with non-curved shapes the default in all new documents I create in Visio. I find curved connectors easier to follow when connectors join. I know other people want no arrow heads on all new documents. This is a common complaint for heavy Visio users.

Here's what I know so far:

- Changing the behaviour after a drawing is done won't cut it, so Select all, Select by type, etc. is not fit for purpose. What if I decide to add more connectors later?
- Changing the document stencil works pretty well. Even at it's best it's an 11 click process that I have to repeat the process for each new document and only after I've added arrows. Better, but not ideal. If you don't know about this, see http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-visio/visio-2013-connectors-can-we-change-these/e6a7a772-cb96-4fbd-8f89-5cbcda0bb1a3?page=1
- Microsoft are bad for making default behaviour so hard/unintuitive to change and they should feel bad

**Desired outcome:**
I need a process that allows me to save the document stencil change to the template(s) Visio uses when creating new documents so that all future documents have my desired connector config as the default

Who ever provides and answer to this will probably be providing an answer to anyone wanting to change any default shape, connector, fill behaviour in Visio.